# can you have reflective xss through a POST parameter?

Tags: web-application, xss, penetration-test, vulnerability, reflected-xss

While testing a dummy app, I noticed that the XSS done through POST parameters was getting stored in the form (the alert('XSS') would show every time I loaded the page where I had injected the payload). Is it possible to have reflective XSS through POST requests?

Comment: Does the reflected XSS payload show up only for you or for anyone on the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP method does not matter for Cross Site Scripting attacks (XSS). It is even possible to get XSS trough the HTTP TRACE method.

> Is it possible to have reflective XSS through POST requests?

Most definitely!